# appendChild appends to right of element in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, appendchild

I am dynamically appending a div to another dynamically created div.  In IE, it shows on the right side of the element, but in all other browsers it shows at the bottom of the element.  I want it to display at the bottom, like it is in FF and Chrome.  Any suggestions?

auto complete works with: `[ "#Saab", "#Volvo", "#BMW", "#Mini", "#MiniMonster" ]`

IE[image: IE display]

non-IE[image: non-IE display]

Solved:
 I was using `divEl.setAttribute("style", "top:" + top + "px; left:" + left + "px; width:" + width + "px;");`

IE has issues with `setAttribute`.  So I switched to:

```
divEl.style.top = top + "px";
divEl.style.width = width + "px";
divEl.style.left = left + "px";
```

Comment: Witch version of IE ? I see same layout in IE9

Comment: IE9 has the problem and so does Opera.  The culprit is the top/left values injected via JS.

Comment: [SOLVED] i was using the setAttribute function.  which IE does not like.  I changed the code to modify the attributes directly and now is working.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [relative](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=relative) positioning in your case, because absolute positioning will always be affected by the size of the window and other factors, it's clear even from your jsFiddle that it appears in the wrong place (using Chrome). 
So, I'd change the CSS to this:

```
#matches_tooltip {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-color: #E0E0E0;
    border-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/9Hg8a/2/

I can't test in IE, but it should be OK in all browsers. Note that I've modified your javascript not to set the position attributes.

Comment: i want to use absolute position so the auto complete appears to overlay the other items in the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.options_text {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And modify your javascript rendering to :

```
element.style {
  bottom: -26px;
  display: inline;
  left: 12px;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 286px;
}
```